# What is the proper ratio of heavy cream to chocolate for a thick ganache?

Tags: chocolate, ganache

Most recipes on the internet call for a 1:1 ratio that I've seen but this ends up being rather watery. I want a thick chocolaty ganache.

Is there anything special that needs to be done to achieve this other than adjusting the ratios? Right now I'm basically doing the "mix simmering heavy cream with chocolate" recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal ganache is 1:1 indeed. You can make a more caramelly one by adding honey and butter:
try 14 oz cream, 12 oz chocolate, 2 oz honey, 6 oz butter diced into small cubes.

Boil the cream and honey together, pour over the chocolate, stir until melted, melt in the butter.

Comment: Yes to Vicky's recipe--that sounds divine! For ganache you can flavor it up a bit by adding a fresh ground spice to the ganache. For example, cardamom is an unexpected by highly complimentary flavor to chocolate.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the cream a little at a time until the chocolate is the consistency you want.  You do not have to have 1:1 you just need enough hot cream to melt the chocolate.
Ganache should not be too thick either.

Answer (score -3):

There is no better way to reduce chocolate ratio but other alternative will just adjust the flavor, you may try cream cheese which will not alter the chocolate flavor that much compares to other alternatives . Next to cheese probably nuts. That will helps in the thickening .